# JavaScript - Store and increase number even after refreshing page

Tags: javascript

This JavaScript code is supposed to increase the number

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var number = 100035;

function increment()
{
    number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + number;
    showNumber(number);
}

function showNumber(num)
{
    document.getElementById("displayDiv").innerHTML = "€" + num;
}

window.onload = function()
{
    setInterval("increment()", 1000);
    showNumber(number);
}
</script>

<div id="displayDiv"></div>
```

I must be able to display the last generated number when users refresh the page and when users return to the website.  However, the number does not continue from the last generated number and instead starts over.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: You could store the value in a cookie

Comment: please how do I store this value in a cookie?

Comment: `localStorage.setItem('number', number);` and `var number = localStorage.getItem('number');`

Comment: Good idea but `localStorage` unfortunately isn't supported by all browsers yet...

Comment: where I insert this code?

Comment: `document.cookie="number=number";`

Comment: Hi Daenu where I insert this code?

Comment: `document.cookie="number=' + number + '";`

Comment: does not work  Please help me

Comment: Did you try my suggested answer?

Comment: yes but does not work

Comment: I realized I was not calling `incrementInterval()` after the window had loaded.  If that doesn't work for you, please comment on my answer and I'll help you track down the issue.

Comment: I have to save the number in the cookie so that when a user is part of the website or refresh the page continues to see the serial number

Comment: Oh, forgive me! The wording of your question had me thinking you wanted it to reset every time the user refreshes the page. I'll correct my answer.

Comment: My updated answer should store the number in a cookie for you and whenever a user returns to the page, the number will start from the value stored in the cookie.  Please comment on my answer *instead* of your question if you have any further issues or questions regarding my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Daenu what do you mean by "localStorage unfortunately isn't supported by all browsers yet... "? [Chrome4+FF4.5+IE8+Opera10.5+Safari4+mobileOS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage#Browser_compatibility) is what we usually call "all browsers", of course we should  say "all *modern* browsers" but still, [you can use](http://caniuse.com/#search=localStorage) `localStorage`.

Comment: @Kaiido You're absolutely right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to avoid using intervals so I use setTimeout here, instead.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var number = checkCookie();
var daysBeforeExpiration = 365;

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var number = getCookie("number");
    if (number == "") {
        number = "100035"
        setCookie("number", number, daysBeforeExpiration);
    }
    return parseInt(number);
}

function showNumber(num)
{
    document.getElementById("displayDiv").innerHTML = "€" + num;
}

incrementInterval = function() {
    showNumber(number);
    number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + number;
    setCookie("number", number.toString(), daysBeforeExpiration)

    setTimeout(incrementInterval, 1000);
};

window.onload = function () {
    incrementInterval();
};
</script>
```

Comment: perfect  you is the best

Comment: I have to install on wordpress playbasis.com is free
 you can help me configure

Comment: I'm not super familiar with that.  I would ask that question on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/